# Blur photos for unauthorized users

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to create a simple feature on my site (React, Node, MongoDB). I have users who can upload their photos, and I want to show their faces blurred for unauthorized visitors. What is the best way of developing this functionality? Saving blurred images separately in DB or calling every time API for blurring images before responding from the backend, or blurring images in frontend. How to make it fast and safe??? Please any help, thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd say saving 2 images on upload, 1 blurred 1 not blurred

Comment: And, the blurred image can likely be much more highly compressed because you don't have detail to preserve so saving two images won't cost much additional storage.

Comment: definitely don't handle it on the frontend. Its easy to remove blurred css from developer toolbar. Handle it at the backend

Comment: Blurring in the front-end can be bypassed without authorization.  Blurring in the back-end cannot be bypassed without authorization.

Comment: Concur, you can't blur front-end. As for what to do the answer is it depends. If you have more compute power than storage, render blurred on server for each image called dynamically. More likely though you're gonna have to store 2 versions blurred / non-blurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything has a pro and con approach.

1. Upload one photo and using a tag in the data such as user object or better yet inside an auth token apply a blur filter to the image. The downside if someone is clever enough they can get the real picture e.g to intercept the download
2. Upload one photo and using a tag in the backend data models or user session reduce the quality of the image on the download. The downside pulling images down will be slower as there has to be image manipulation before its sent to the front end.
3. Upload two images one normal and one low quality. Downside longer initial upload and you are now taking up more space in your image bucket which will cost you more money.

There will be more approaches but each will have a trade-off between speed, security and cost/space. I personally would go with number three if the cost is not an issue and if you use good compression and don't get snowballed with users the cost difference should not be that much.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your use case blurring images on frontend after calling an API to verify whether user is authorised or not is least secure. Saving two images on upload seems like a good idea but it's a bit waste as you're saving same image twice. I would go with blurring images on the backend.